# Combine Multiple Splines into One

Tags: spline

[image]

The above image is a sample of my project. Am creating a road map using Rectangular Splines.
There are approximately 2000 such rectangular spline.
As seen in the above image Stage 1 is the initial Structure and stage 3 is the final Outcome
I have used Attach to combine all the splines.
The thing I am trying to achieve is I want to convert The spline in one and Remove the inner edges to Optimize the Game Performance.

Is there any way to do that. Doing manually is very tough and there are nearly 30 level each containing 2000 splines

Comment: What is a "rectangular spline"? Is it a spline that shapes like a rectangle?

Comment: yes [Rectangle Spline](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/files/GUID-1DCE5122-A0FE-43A7-AED0-FED1098BBC18.htm)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Seems like this "Rectangular Spline" is just a spline that shapes like a rectangle. What you want to do can be achieved in the following ways:

1) Break up all the rectangular splines into straight lines. Your rectangular splines most likely are just degree 1 B-splines, so it should be quite easy to break them up.
2) Find identical straight line segments. If you found two identical line segments, delete both of them. 
3) You will be left with many straight line segments that form the outside perimeter of those 3 regions as shown in your picture stage 3. You will need to sort all these line segments into 3 loops and join the line segments in each loop back to a degree 1 B-spline.